# Different aes-128-cbc between C# and openssl

Tags: c#, openssl, aes

I'm trying to decrypt this data, given a key and an IV, but the result is different between c# and openssl

Openssl operation:

```
### client key
$ hexkey=f656d037b173ef3e11169f27231a84b6
### IV for this record
$ hexiv=404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f
### encrypted data
$ echo '22 7b c9 ba 81 ef 30 f2 a8 a7 8f f1 df 50 84 4d'  > /tmp/msg1
$ echo '58 04 b7 ee b2 e2 14 c3 2b 68 92 ac a3 db 7b 78' >> /tmp/msg1
$ echo '07 7f dd 90 06 7c 51 6b ac b3 ba 90 de df 72 0f' >> /tmp/msg1
$ xxd -r -p /tmp/msg1 \
  | openssl enc -d -nopad -aes-128-cbc -K $hexkey -iv $hexiv | hexdump
```

C# operation:

```
 public static string DecryptWithOpenSSL(byte[] base64CipherText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
        {
            try
            {
                using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
                {
                    aesAlg.Key = key;
                    aesAlg.IV = iv;
                    aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

                    ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                    using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(base64CipherText))
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {
                        return srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error decrypting data: " + ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Openssl result:
`14 00 00 0c cf 91 96 26 f1 36 0c 53 6a aa d7 3a .......`
C# result:
`14 00 00 0C CF 91 EFBFBD26EFBFBD360C536AEFBFBDEFBFBD3AEFBFBD`

The key and IV are in the correct format.
As you can see, only first 6 bytes looks the same.
If anyone could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer will likely help you get past the bump. But if you're interested, I'll try to explain what your strange C# result means.

If you squint hard at your 2 different outputs, you'll see that they actually line up nicely like so:

```
(SSL) 14 00 00 0C CF 91 [96    ] 26 [F1    ] 36 0C 53 ...
(C#)  14 00 00 0C CF 91 [EFBFBD] 26 [EFBFBD] 36 0C 53 ...
```

Here's a useful tip: If you ever see `0xEFBFBD`, you should stop and immediately suspect that you've run into a UTF-8 encoding issue. It is what's known as the [Unicode REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) (scroll down till you get to UTF-8 and you'll see the magic sequence).

`StreamReader` is designed to read strings, and it [defaults to UTF-8 encoding unless specified otherwise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-7.0#remarks). And that is why you're seeing what you are seeing.

Without getting bogged down on the encoding process ([Wikipedia's explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding) isn't the best but it'll do), both your problematic characters (`96` and `F1`) are not meant to sit where they are in a valid UTF-8 sequence.

The sequence you have `0xCF/91/96` is `11001111/10010001/10010110` in binary. `CF` starts with `110` which means it's the first of a 2-byte sequence. The next byte, `91` starts with `10` meaning it's a continuation (second part of the 2-byte sequence).
The next byte (your problematic character `96`) also starts with `10` - supposedly another "continuation byte". But we're not expecting another continuation! We have completed the 2-byte sequence. So the decoder freaks out and throws in your magic `EFBFBD`/�/REPLACEMENT CHARACTER in its place.

Similarly, `F1` is `11110001` which is meant to be the first of a 4-byte sequence. But none of the following bytes have the "continuation" marker. Another freak out.

So yeah, character encoding is a funny -but interesting- rabbit hole to fall into.

Answer (score 2):

Because you were using a `StreamReader`, I'm surprised it didn't throw any exceptions... `StreamReader` is used to read text not binary data. To read binary data you can copy the `CryptoStream` to a `MemoryStream` (or any other streams such as a `FileStream`)

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
csDecrypt.CopyTo(ms);
var bytes = ms.ToArray();
```